# Why does my program not loop properly when printing a 2D array table?

Tags: c++, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create an 2D array table in C++ with a for loop and this is my code below.

```
//receive user input

double nSideA = sSideA;
for ( double x = nSideA; x < eSideA; x = x + incrementA) {
    cout << "a=" << fixed << setprecision(1)  << setw(4) << nSideA << " ";
    nSideA += incrementA;
} // table header

cout << "\n"; //spacing

for (double y = sSideB; y < eSideB; y = y + incrementB) {
    for (double x = sSideA; x < eSideA; x = x + incrementA) {
        sSideA += incrementA;
        sSideB += incrementB;
        hypo = sqrt( pow(sSideA,2) + pow(sSideB,2) );
        cout << "b=" << fixed << setprecision(1)  << setw(4) << sSideB << " ";
        cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << setw(3) << hypo << " " << endl;
    }
} // content
```

My output for the table is something like :

```
b= 2.0 2.828
b= 3.0 4.243
b= 4.0 5.657
b= 5.0 7.071
b= 6.0 8.485
b= 7.0 9.899
```

with b not looping properly. (Printed all in a column thanks to Frax in the comments with `endl;`)

This is supposed to be a program that performs the Pythagoras Theorem. I intend for my output to be like

> |  | Column 0 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Row 0 | a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[0][2] | a[0][3] |
> | Row 1 | a[1][0] | a[1][1] | a[1][2] | a[1][3] |
> | Row 2 | a[2][0] | a[2][1] | a[2][2] | a[2][3] |

However, the results go wrong on the second loop where `a[1][1]` ends up at `a[1][0]` , `a[2][2]` ends up at `a[2][0]` and so on.

How do I fix my `for` loop to make it print a proper table?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to break a line when printing? How to get a graphical output? Perhaps what you need is just `cout << endl;` added in proper places.

Comment: Are you trying to itterate through every value in each demension ?

Comment: Thank you Frax, `endl` got me closer to the result I wanted. I edited my post.

Comment: I'm trying to get a value for all possible combinations of `sSideA` and `sSideB` with they formula in for `hypo` into a table

Comment: Floating point (e.g. `double`) is not precise, so it is usually better to use an integer to control a loop, if you want control over the exact number of iterations.  If you need a value of type `double`, compute it from the loop index.   Also `pow(sSideA,2)` is usually better expressed as `sSideA*sSideA` - it is rare that the operation(s) for exponentiation are more effective (e.g. precision-wise, performance) than a single multiplication.

Comment: @Peter can you elaborate on what you mean by computing it from the loop index?

Comment: Assuming `n` is the number of loop iterations, and you want to run from `left` to `right` in steps of `increment`,  try `for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {value = left + (i-1)*increment; ..... }`.